# Obj-C: Class methods vs instance methods -- efficiency difference?

Tags: objective-c, performance, class-method

For the sake of tidiness and reusability, I'm thinking about putting a bunch of utility methods inside a single class. The class does not require any properties of its own and so I will define the methods as class methods; I figure that's there's no real need to have an instance of this class floating around…

…or is there? Is there a difference in efficiency? (A noticeable one?) Or does calling class methods behave in the same way as if they were part of the calling class?

Comment: My guess is that instance methods are slightly faster to call than class methods.  But that's only a guess.  But for the most part they're going to pretty much the same -- both are similar dynamic calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dandan78 has the correct answer in general. It's always best to measure your code yourself. In fact, for this problem, you should probably just implement it the way you want, and then measure, and only change it if it's significantly slowing down your app.

Gavin is also correct that C functions are more efficient than class or instance methods. But again, unless you're calling these methods millions of times in a tight loop, the overhead of a method vs a C function probably won't matter to your application.

But to answer the question asked, there's basically no difference between class methods and instance methods. In Objective-C, classes are actually objects themselves, and sending messages to them is identical to sending a message to an instance object. Each class basically has a singleton object that class methods are called on.

Answer (score 3):

As in all cases regarding efficiency-related dilemmas, your best bet is to do what makes sense from a coding point of view -- make the code as intuitive and reader-friendly as you can. If it turns out that something is not as fast as it needs to be, profile and optimize accordingly.

And although I don't expect there to be any difference in this case, you can make a class and a instance version of a method, run it a million times in a loop preceded and followed by `[NSDate date]` calls, then compare the times.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way would be to make them C functions, actually. You'll avoid the overhead of the Objective-C runtime every time you call one of them. Obviously based on the wording of your question, you don't need extra state that you keep around for these utility methods, since you were thinking about making them class methods anyway.

When I keep around utility methods like this, I most of the time make them C functions, because it's cleanest and most efficient. When I might make an Objective-C class with them as methods is if they have something in common with each other where it makes sense to have them organized this way, or if I need to keep state around for them.

Comment: Correct in absolute terms. In reality, the overhead of objc_msgSend is tiny.

Comment: @bbum But utility functions could easily get used in tight loops, in which case the overhead could make a measurable difference. Besides, if they're just utility functions that don't need or necessarily belong in an Objective-C class, there's little reason not to go this route. The class route mainly only makes sense if you need to keep some state or other data around.

Comment: Yeah -- agreed.  If that is the case, then going full on `static inline` is likely the right call.   I was more pointing out that the overhead of a method call vs. a C function is trivially small.   If it is enough to make a difference, it is more likely the case that you have an algorithmic problem.

Answer (score 2):

[I made a sample project](https://github.com/MaxGabriel/ClassVInstance) that compares calling instance methods to class methods or a C function. Here's some example output:

```
Class methods:    Time to complete: 0.00415796
Single instance:  Time to complete: 0.00437099
Using Singleton:  Time to complete: 0.071667
Using Global:     Time to complete: 0.00534797
Using C function: Time to complete: 0.00302202
```

The primary conclusion you should get from this is that the *differences are negligible*; use Instruments to profile for actual performance bottlenecks.

To get back to your original question, you should use a class method, since your methods don't depend on any state (properties) that an instance might hold. Performance wise, this can only help because using an actual instance means you have to allocate and access that instance somehow, which adds overhead (again, all this is negligible).

Using a C function will be unnoticeably quicker, but you won't be able to subclass and override that C function like you would a class method.

Comment: That singleton result is surprising. I would have thought it would have been more similar to the single instance result.

Comment: Depends on implementation.

Comment: The singleton result has the added overhead of first calling a method every single time to get the singleton before calling the desired method on it, plus it probably makes it harder for the compiler to optimize the code and might make it less cache-friendly. It would be almost equal to the Single Instance result if we just retrieved the singleton and kept it in a local variable. As for subclassing, people wouldn't generally subclass utility functions, so it would be unlikely that an Objective-C class would be necessary for it. And performance critical code would see a difference.

Comment: @Gavin There is no missing optimization and the extra method call should really only incur about the same CPU time as calling a class method.   There is something else going on here;  I'd be surprised -- but not completely -- if that were using `dispatch_once`.  It may also be that this was not optimized code and, under ARC, that may incur extra retain/release calls.